# Calling another variable inside a variable assignment

Tags: bash, variables

My line of code is :

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
    echo "**"
    CURL_REQ=$(curl -is "${line}"  -H 'Pragma: akamai-x-get-extracted-values' | grep 'AKA_PM_PROPERTY_NAME')
    echo "$line"
    echo "$CURL_REQ"
```

After doing some trial an error, I now understood that inside variable declaration of "CURL_REQ"
${line} is not being recognized.
However the echo "$line" is working perfectly without any issues outside the variable declaration.

When I replace "${line}" with a static hostname, the curl works fine and I can see the value on echo "$CURL_REQ"

Reproducible example :

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT_FILE="/domain.txt"
EXPECTED_HEADER="AKA_PM_PROPERTY_NAME"
declare -i COUNT=1

echo "*************************************************************************"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    CURL_REQ=$(curl -is ${line} -H 'Pragma: akamai-x-get-extracted-values' | grep 'AKA_PM_PROPERTY_NAME')
    echo "$line"
    echo $CURL_REQ
    PROP_VALUE=$(echo ${CURL_REQ} | cut -c 51-)
    echo $PROP_VALUE
    
done < "$INPUT_FILE"
```

Input file domain.txt should contain the lines below :

myntra.com
ndtv.com

Comment: replace `echo "$line"` with `declare -p line` and see if it has a trailing `\r`

Comment: Why do you think that `${line}` is not recognized? What happens if you replace the declaration with `CURL_REQ=$(echo "$line")`? My suspicion is that grep does not work as you intended. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e. in this case a short example of a file which should produce some expected output?

Comment: Here's a small reproducible example : INPUT_FILE="/domain.txt"
EXPECTED_HEADER="AKA_PM_PROPERTY_NAME"
declare -i COUNT=1

echo "*************************************************************************"

while IFS= read -r line
do
 CURL_REQ=$(curl -is ${line} -H 'Pragma: akamai-x-get-extracted-values' | grep 'AKA_PM_PROPERTY_NAME')
 echo "$line"
 echo $CURL_REQ
 PROP_VALUE=$(echo ${CURL_REQ} | cut -c 51-)
 echo $PROP_VALUE
 
done < "$INPUT_FILE"

Comment: input text file containing these two lines : myntra.com ndtv.com

Comment: Almost certain your input file contains DOS line endings. See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/8656552) use all [caps](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details. Don't use comments. Code is unreadable in comments, and comments are show in order of votes, not by time posted or author. See also [ask].

Comment: Sorry. New to Stack overflow. I have added the code in the details now.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks I think what is the problem. I created a new input file and ran the script. It works. My original file was downloaded off internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mhs Based on your provided script, seems it is working for me - I have only changed the `INPUT_FILE="/domain.txt"` to `INPUT_FILE="./domain.txt"` to read the file from the same directory that I am running the script.

Here are the details, please compare them with yours and you'd find the issue on your side.

IMHO the `domain.txt` file's context or permissions (accessibility) should be the problem.

*Note: The `script.sh` and the `domain.txt` files are both in the same directory (my user's home directory) and they have proper permissions relevant to user (my user) that I'm running the script*

If you didn't find the issue, I'll suggest re-format your question and provide step by step description and **details** as I have in the following.

- The `script.sh` file content I'm running:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_FILE="./domain.txt"
EXPECTED_HEADER="AKA_PM_PROPERTY_NAME"
declare -i COUNT=1

echo "*************************************************************************"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    CURL_REQ=$(curl -is ${line} -H 'Pragma: akamai-x-get-extracted-values' | grep 'AKA_PM_PROPERTY_NAME')
    echo "$line"
    echo $CURL_REQ
    PROP_VALUE=$(echo ${CURL_REQ} | cut -c 51-)
    echo $PROP_VALUE

done < "$INPUT_FILE"
```

- The `domain.txt` file content:

```
myntra.com
ndtv.com
```

- Here are the files permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 vrej vrej   20 Jan  5 17:18 domain.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vrej vrej  440 Jan  5 17:18 script.sh
```

- The output that I get is:

```
*************************************************************************
myntra.com
X-Akamai-Session-Info: name=AKA_PM_PROPERTY_NAME; value=www.myntra.com_ssl
value=www.myntra.com_ssl
ndtv.com
X-Akamai-Session-Info: name=AKA_PM_PROPERTY_NAME; value=www.ndtv.com-EON-1501
value=www.ndtv.com-EON-1501
```

- My BASH version is:

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answers. You are right. The problem was on the content of the Input file. What I did is created a new input file and ran the same script. It works whereas the original input file which I got causes the problem.  Another user @tripleee also mentioned the bash script is encoding sensitive. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Glad that you find the issue, good luck.